# paging over SELECT UNION super slow and killing my server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have an SP that returns paged data from a query that contains a UNION.  This is killing my DB and taking 30 seconds to run sometimes, am I missing something obvious here?  What can I do to improve it's performance?

Tables Involved: Products, Categories, CategoryProducts

Goal:
Any Products that are not in a Category or have been deleted from a category UNION all Products currently in a category and page over them for a web service.

I have Indexes on all columns that I am joining on and there are 427,996 Products, 6148 Categories and 409,691 CategoryProducts  in the database.

Here is my query that is taking between 6, and 30 seconds to run:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.ItemID, Products.ManufacturerID) AS RowNum, *
        FROM
        (
        SELECT  Products.*,
              CategoryID = NULL, CategoryName = NULL, 
              CategoryProductID = NULL, 
                          ContainerMinimumQuantity = 
                            CASE  COALESCE(Products.ContainerMinQty, 0)
                                WHEN 0 THEN Products.OrderMinimumQuantity
                                ELSE Products.ContainerMinQty
                            END 
                            Products.IsDeleted, 
                           SortOrder = NULL
    FROM    CategoryProducts RIGHT OUTER JOIN   Products 
        ON CategoryProducts.ManufacturerID = Products.ManufacturerID 
            AND CategoryProducts.ItemID = Products.ItemID
            WHERE     (Products.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID)
                AND (Products.ModifiedOn > @tStamp )
                 AND  ((CategoryProducts.IsDeleted = 1) OR (CategoryProducts.IsDeleted IS NULL))

                UNION

                SELECT Products.*, 
 CategoryProducts.CategoryID , CategoryProducts.CategoryName, 
          CategoryProducts.CategoryProductID , 
                          ContainerMinimumQuantity = 
                            CASE  COALESCE(Products.ContainerMinQty, 0)
                                WHEN 0 THEN Products.OrderMinimumQuantity
                                ELSE Products.ContainerMinQty
                            END 
                            CategoryProducts.IsDeleted,
                           CategoryProducts.SortOrder
    FROM      Categories INNER JOIN
                          CategoryProducts ON Categories.CategoryID = CategoryProducts.CategoryID INNER JOIN
                          Products ON CategoryProducts.ManufacturerID = Products.ManufacturerID
             AND CategoryProducts.ItemID = Products.ItemID
    WHERE     (Products.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID) 
            AND  (Products.ModifiedOn > @tStamp OR  CategoryProducts.ModifiedOn > @tStamp))  
            AS Products) AS C 
        WHERE RowNum >= @StartRow AND RowNum <= @EndRow
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before even looking at the query, can you tell me what the execution plan looks like?  (The bulk, ie is it doing an index scan?)

Comment: Is union necessary, or will union all work?

Comment: @TimLehner I do not think it will make a difference to me - does that greatly impact performance?

Comment: Paste went wrong. There are three columns missing in after union select - CategoryID, CategoryName and CategoryProductID. As two queries are very similar, and might be resolved by outer joins and a bit more detailed where, why don't you try to unite the two? This would allow you to move row_number() into the same level as a query.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I fixed my paste problem so it reflects what I am actually using

Comment: @dbaseman 48% on Clustered Index Scan in CategoryProducts and 41% on Key Lookup in Products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your situation correctly, the only reason for having two distinct queries is treatment of missing/deleted CategoryProducts. I tried to address this issue by left join with `IsDeleted = 0` to bring all deleted CategoryProducts to nulls, so I don't have to test them again. ModifiedOn part got another test for null for missing/deleted Categoryproducts you wish to retrieve.

```
select *
from (
    SELECT 
      Products.*, 
      -- Following three columns will be null for deleted/missing categories
      CategoryProducts.CategoryID, 
      CategoryProducts.CategoryName, 
      CategoryProducts.CategoryProductID , 
      ContainerMinimumQuantity = COALESCE(nullif(Products.ContainerMinQty, 0),
                                          Products.OrderMinimumQuantity),
      CategoryProducts.IsDeleted,
      CategoryProducts.SortOrder,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.ItemID, 
                                 Products.ManufacturerID) AS RowNum
    FROM Products 
      LEFT JOIN CategoryProducts 
         ON CategoryProducts.ManufacturerID = Products.ManufacturerID
        AND CategoryProducts.ItemID = Products.ItemID
    -- Filter IsDeleted in join so we get nulls for deleted categories
    -- And treat them the same as missing ones
        AND CategoryProducts.IsDeleted = 0
      LEFT JOIN Categories
         ON Categories.CategoryID = CategoryProducts.CategoryID 
    WHERE Products.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID
      AND (Products.ModifiedOn > @tStamp 
        -- Deleted/missing categories
           OR CategoryProducts.ModifiedOn is null
           OR CategoryProducts.ModifiedOn > @tStamp)
    ) C
WHERE RowNum >= @StartRow AND RowNum <= @EndRow
```

On a third look I don't see that Category is used at all except as a filter to  CategoryProducts. If this is the case second LEFT JOIN should be changed to INNER JOIN and this section should be enclosed in parenthessis.